# Displaying Child Elements in AngularJS Tree on Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mouseclick-event

I have an angular js tree I am using from here: https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree

What I am trying to figure out is how to take my list of parents with children, and have those parents, when clicked, load their children from a service. There is a lot of data, so I can't just load everything into the tree, and I am confused about how each child will bind to a model when there could be any number of unique children.

Here is what I have so far(some of it is pseudo code designated with "???"). Currently the tree loads a list of parent nodes.

```
  <div ui-tree>
            <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="GaccList">
                <li ng-repeat="gacc in GaccList" ui-tree-node>
                    <div ui-tree-handle>
                        {{gacc.Name}}
                    </div>
                   <!-- these are my children of the parent.-->
                    <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-click="SomeFunctionToLoadIncidentsForThisSpecificIncident(???)" ng-model="IncidentList[???]" >
                        <li ng-repeat="subItem in IncidentList[???]" ui-tree-node>
                            <div ui-tree-handle>
                                {{subItem.title}}
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ol> 

                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you need exactly two levels (parents, children) or an unknown number of levels?

Comment: I think you will need to define arrays for every repeater. So you might have `$scope.gaccs = [{name: 'gacc1', incidents: [] }, ... ]` and then the inner repeaters would use `incident in gacc.incidents`. Then you can load data into the arrays later.

Comment: I will have 12 predefined parents, but they could have X number of children, and those children can have X number of children. So the max depth for the tree is 3.

Comment: You will probably want to start with an empty tree then and add the elements on the fly. I don't remember whether the angular-ui-tree directive will automatically execute when you add the element, you might have to do something with scope.apply... And you will probably want to construct partials for the second and third level list items

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!That is what I ended up doing.